# Python - Trying to use Chromedriver Auto install option for one of my automation

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver

I need help in correcting the code or to understand where i am going wrong here. I am trying to open Chrome using chrome driver auto install option in Python. Using Python IDLE to run this code. It's giving:

`ValueError: Timeout value connect was <object object at 0x000001140A1A54E0> but it must be an int, float or None`

Below is the code i tried

```py
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
```

### Initialize Chrome WebDriver

```py
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
```

### Open a webpage

```py
driver.get("https://www.**********.com/")
```

### Close the browser

```py
driver.quit()
```